# Strange problem with differential amplifier for current sensing with TL084

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement

I have a problem with the circuit below:

[image]

I'm using the op-amp as differential amplifier for low-side current sensing with gain of 100. All resistors are 0.1% and the load is just a variable resistor for testing the circuit.

The problem is no matter what load I have and how much current is going through the sense resistor the output of the op-amp is around 23 - 24 volts. I tried switching all of the components checked all the connections and even rebuilt the circuit on a bread board with no avail. I feel like there is something obvious that I'm missing.

I have the same circuit in simulator and it works just fine.

**Update:** As I mentioned I did miss something obvious and didn't check the datasheet fully.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can't drive the input common mode voltage to 0V.

Have you tried to connect the load to GND and the shunt to 24v?

[TL084 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tl084)

Comment: Thank you, I know I was missing something obvious; I built the circuit with what I had laying around and didn't check the datasheet fully.

Comment: I won't be able to connect the load to ground and shunt to the power since the final voltage of the load will be above what the op-amp can handle.

Comment: @Oli Analog Devices makes Over the Top opamps that can have their inputs go way over the supply voltage.

Comment: Swapping the load & shunt will only help with the TL08x**H** version. The others can't operate with Vcm at Vcc (as shown in the datasheet snippet now posted by the OP).

Comment: What will the Isense voltage be max? Can likely run the chip from +/-12v just fine.

Comment: @rdtsc The circuit doesn't have negative voltage supply, It's much easier to switch the op-amp itself.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, As mentioned, I built it with what I had on me; I have ordered new op-amps.